# How can you use non-default Function keys?

Tags: azure, azure-functions

In the azure functions there is the option of adding `function keys`.  How do you accept keys other than the default?

```
https://xxxxxxx.azurewebsites.net/api/webhook?code=kjsdfklhsdf==
```

where `kjsdfklhsdf==` is the default key.  how can i use a different key?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Under your function in the "Manage" section there is UI for adding new keys. Select "Add new function key", give it a name and select "Save" leaving the value empty. A new key will be generated for you.

Once you add a new key, you can simply copy its value and use it as the `code` query parameter in your requests.

If your function is a **WebHook** (as opposed to a regular http function), when using a key other than the default you must also specify the `clientId` as a query param (the client ID is the name of your new key):

```
https://<site>.azurewebsites.net/api/webhook?code=<code>&clientId=<keyName>
```

This is documented more [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk-script/wiki/Http-Functions#webhooks) in the WebHooks section of our wiki.

Comment: Ah, you were using a WebHook - I've updated my answer